# Additional price based on cart item count in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, fee

Based on *"[woocommerce change price in checkout and cart page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43284017/woocommerce-change-price-in-checkout-and-cart-page)"* answer code that change the total price in checkout page, I have added some extra code to count the products that user have in cart and if user had like 9 products in cart then add some price to total:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_totals', 'custom_cart_total' , 'get_cart_contents_count');
function custom_cart_total() {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
            return;
    if (WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 9){
        WC()->cart->total += 15;
    }
    elseif(WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 6){
       WC()->cart->total += 14; 
    }
    elseif(WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 4){
       WC()->cart->total += 13; 
    }

}
```

**But it doesn't work.** This image will explain everything:

[image]

I will appreciate if anyone could correct the code and tell me how can I display the message like in the picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should better use the FEE API instead, this way:

```
// Add a custom packing fee based on item count
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'custom_packing_fee', 10, 1 );
function custom_packing_fee( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    $count = $cart->get_cart_contents_count();

    if ( $count >= 9 ){
        $fee = 15;
    }
    elseif( $count >= 6 && $count < 9 ){
        $fee = 14;
    }
    elseif( $count >= 4 && $count < 6 ){
        $fee = 13;
    }

    if ( isset($fee) && $fee > 0 ) {
        $label = sprintf( __('Box fee (%d items)'), $count);
        $cart->add_fee( $label, $fee, false );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme *(or active theme)*. Tested and works.

> If you want to **enable taxes** for the packing fee, change the third argument from `false` to `true`.